# Saving the Votes from a Polling App in a Mongo Database

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, polling

I created a Polling Application with node.js
Now I want to save the Votes in a Database. But I just get an error 
Even I installed mongodb and mongoose
Here is my Code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

//Map global promises
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
//Mongoose Connect
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp', {useNewUrlParser: true});
.then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected'))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: are you getting the console in the backend that MongoDb is connected ?

Comment: no. Do you know what I can do ?

Comment: i have provided the code pls replace it and then check

Answer (score 0):

replace this code with your code and check whether you are getting the console or not

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myapp',(err) => {
   if (err) {
      console.log('Sorry can not connect with mongodb...');
   } else {
      console.log('Successfully connected mongodb...');
   }
});
```

Comment: I get the message:    if (err) {
      console.log('Sorry can not connect with mongodb...');

Comment: `mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp`  put this and check again, i think you have not install the mongo properly , you can check it using this  `mongo` in your terminal or `mongodb` in your terminal

Comment: He cant find "mongo" or "mongodb". But I thought I installed mongo with "npm install mongodb" in my projectfolder.

Comment: can you confirm that whether your mongo service is running or connected , you can check using this command `service mongob status` https://vitalflux.com/mongodb-commands-check-status-database/

Comment: how do i run mongodb?

Comment: yaa, then its not the problem related to the project , you should install the mongodb again and then check the `service mongob status` is  running or not

Comment: which operating system  you are using

Comment: @YoungProgrammer1009 did you get the solutions

Comment: No I did not get the solution. I am using node.js

Comment: which operating system you are using i will help you to getout of this problem

Comment: Thank you ! I am using windows

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/  OR https://medium.com/@LondonAppBrewery/how-to-download-install-mongodb-on-windows-4ee4b3493514 install the mpngo properly and than try the above code , it will work for you

Comment: @YoungProgrammer1009 thats great to hear that your problem is solved so can you mark the answer as correct and upvote it ,you should also mark it as correct answer, so that if other come for a solution they can easy get to know that this solution work for you